# extrude works like ctrl + extrude

Tags: extrude, units

When I hit <kbd>E</kbd> without holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> it extrudes by units. When I hit <kbd>E</kbd> holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> it extrudes normally. How to swap that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the Snap option (magnet icon button on the bottom horizontal menu bar of the 3D View)